# linux find regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, find

I'm having trouble using the regex of the `find` command. Probably something I don't understand about escaping on the command line.

Why are these not the same?

```
find -regex '.*[1234567890]'
find -regex '.*[[:digit:]]'
```

Bash, Ubuntu

Comment: What output do you have to indicate that they are not?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Regular expressions with character classes (e.g. `[[:digit:]]`) are not supported in the default regular expression syntax used by `find`. You need to specify a different regex type such as `posix-extended` in order to use them.

Take a look at GNU Find's Regular Expression [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions) which shows you all the regex types and what they support.

Comment: Thanks. That document is the one I should have been looking for. All I could find was http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes - which seemed to suggest that character classes *were* supported in "emacs regex mode".

Comment: Also check [Regular_expression#Character_classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) - very helpful resource

Answer (score 73):

You should have a look on the `-regextype` argument of `find`, see [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/find.1.html):

```
      -regextype type
          Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex 
          tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently-implemented  
          types  are  emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-basic, 
          posix-egrep and posix-extended.
```

I guess the `emacs` type doesn't support the `[[:digit:]]` construct. I tried it with `posix-extended` and it worked as expected:

```
find -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[1234567890]'
find -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[[:digit:]]'
```

Comment: I thought it might be that, but I checked the emacs regex definitions and they appear to support [:digit:]. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes

Answer (score 30):

Note that `-regex` depends on whole path.

```
 -regex pattern
              File name matches regular expression pattern.  
              This is a match on the whole path, not a search.
```

You don't actually have to use `-regex` for what you are doing.

```
find . -iname "*[0-9]"
```

Comment: The excplicit dot is unneeded here, too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may try this `'.*[0-9]'`