# repetition in GNU find regexp

Tags: regex, find

I am trying to find all the files whose name contains exactly 14 digits (I'm trying to match a timestamp in the filename). I'm not sure how to get the GNU find regexp syntax for repetitions right.

I've tried `find -regex ".*[0-9]{14}` and `find -regex ".*[0-9]\{14\}`, neither of these turns up any results. Can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: What are you matching them against?

Comment: The top answer here by Susam Pal worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remember, GNU `find's -regex` matches a whole path. Anyway, you can use a combination of `find` and `grep` to do the task, eg to find exactly 14 digits with no other characters

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\n" | grep -E "\b[0-9]{14}\b"
```

modify to suit your needs

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the -regextype parameter to find.

> Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex
>   tests which occur later on the  command  line.   Currently-implemented
>   types are emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-basic,
>   posix-egrep and posix-extended.

Answer (score 1):

1. -regextype should match your -regex or -iregex
2. **the -regex and -iregex must occur later on the command line.**
3. -regex matches whole path

Example:

```
$ find . -regextype grep -regex '.*/[0-9]\{14\}.*'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
./00000000000054                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
./00000000000098                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
./00000000000042                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
./00000000000075                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
./00000000000027                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
./00000000000080                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
./00000000000083                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
./00000000000077
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I just gave it a try and I could not get this work. Here's a workaround anyway (matching 2 consecutive numbers):

```
$ls
a123.txt  a1b2c3.txt  a45.txt  b123.txt
$find -regex '.*[^0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9].*'
./a45.txt
```