# Regular Expression to Exclude Filetypes in Find

Tags: regex, find

I'm fairly new to find and regular expressions have always been tricky for me. I am hoping someone can quickly correct this for me and maybe even tell me why this isn't doing that I think it should (exclude files of certain types is the goal):

```
find . -type f \( -name "*" ! -name "*\.(vm | jar | class | htm | html | jpg | gif)$" \)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why -name "*" and then the second pattern? Isn't -not -name "*\.(vm..." enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the question is about a Unix shell...

Anyway, on the regex side, which I know better, I think you must remove the whitespaces you have in your expression:

```
"\.(vm|jar|class|html?|jpg|gif)$"
```

I don't guarantee the validity of your command itself...

Comment: Not 100% correct, what about file: `handjar` it hasn't got extension but would still match.

Comment: Good remark, I edit... Thanks. Not even sure if `find` does a full match or match anywhere. In the first case, your answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the find command syntax, but to match files with given extension you would need:

```
".*\.(vm|jar|class|htm|html|jpg|gif)$"
```

Removed spaces and added dot at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure **find** looks for every names by default, so your extra "**-name "*"**" is not necessary here.

On the regexp side, it looks like you've found the answer you were looking for, but you might still want to know that **find** has an **OR** flag (-or or -o) that can make things easier when regular expressions are causing you troubles:

```
find . -type f ! \( -name "*.vm" -o -name "*.jar" -o -name ".class" \)
```

On the downside, it's obviously longer to write...

Remember to take a look at [man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

Good luck