# Scp bulk files from current directory to another directory

Tags: linux, shell

I need to transfer a bunch of files from a production host to my local machine. I'm already in the directory that I need to transfer the files from. I know the names of log files that I need to transfer to my local machine. They are log.timestamp.hostnames and these tend to be long. How can I transfer in bulk using scp ? Is there an easier way than just typing the long file names ? Can I get it out from a filename ?

Answer (score 6):

Use wildcards:

```
scp log.* user@host:/target/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to copy over all of your files in the current directory (which would just be using ./*), what you could do is parse all of the files in your current directory and run a regular expression on it to match up log.timestamp.hostname then pipe that into scp. For the regex I found this example [regex with find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command). To send big files here is an example: [scp syntax](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/pipe-find-output-to-scp-415131/). Something along the lines of:

```
scp $(find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/log\.[a-z0-9\-]\.[a-z0-9\-]") user@remote:~/
```

You will probably want to modify the regex to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This command line execution option helped to solve my issue of transfering a subset of files. As the AIX unix does not provide the -regextype option with find I used the grep command instead in order to retrieve files tab1.msg to tab9 msg

```
scp $(find . -name "*" | grep tab.\.msg)  user@host:/tmp
```