# find command with -regex in FreeBSD

Tags: regex, macos, terminal, find, freebsd

I've done [quite a lot of research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command) and tried each and every technique listed (some don't work on freebsd/osx), yet when i use the find command for the utmost simple search it comes back empty.

I have a directory full of files like:

```
file_name_one.ext
_something.ext
some_other_file.ext
maybe_one_more.ext
```

I've tried the following to find all files containing an underscore:

```
find . -regex "_"
find . -regex _
find . -name "_"
find . -regex "_"
find . -regex "\_"
find . -regex "_.*"
find . -regex "\_,*"
find . -regex "\_.*"
find . -name "_" -print 
find . -regex '_'
find . -regex '\(_\)'
find . -regex '$\137'
find . -regex '\137'
find . -regex '(_)'
find . -regex '\x5F'
find . -regex '.*\x5F'
find . -regex '.*/[\x5F/]
find . -regex '.*/[\x5F/]'
find . -regex '/_/'
find -E . -regex '.*/[^_/]'
find -E . -regex '\137'
find -E . -regex '\137' -print
find -E . -regex '$\137'
find -E . -regex '(_)'
find . -regextype sed -regex "_"
```

**with NO LUCK**
...what in heck is going on here? why doesn't it match any files containing an underscore?

Comment: Try `find . -name '*_*'` or `find . -regex '.*_.*'` The man page says that the regex needs to match the entire path. Actually, `find . -regex '.*/.*_.*'` is probably better, so that you don't unintentionally match paths like ./a_b/c

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down the question into the significant parts. You want to:

- find files
- that have an underscore in the filename.

For finding only regular files, use `-type f`. For finding names that contain a certain character, use `-name` and a shell pattern.

From the documentation;

> ```
>  -type t
>          True if the file is of the specified type.  Possible file types
>          are as follows:
>
>          b       block special
>          c       character special
>          d       directory
>          f       regular file
>          l       symbolic link
>          p       FIFO
>          s       socket
> ```

and

> ```
>  -name pattern
>          True if the last component of the pathname being examined matches
>          pattern. Special shell pattern matching characters (“[”, “]”,
>          “*”, and “?”) may be used as part of pattern. These characters
>          may be matched explicitly by escaping them with a backslash
>          (“\”).
> ```

So:

```
find -s . -type f -name '*_*'
```

The `-s` option is used for sorting the results.

You should use `-regex` if you want to match the *whole path* and if you require an expression that is not reproducable in a shell pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could spice it up with any of the following regular expressions:

```
find . -type f -regex ".*_.*"
find . -type f -regex '.*_.*'
find . -type f -regex .*_.*
```

What you missed in your first example was that something could come before/after the underscore, hence the `.*`, where `.` equals any character (except line breaks) and `*` equals zero or more characters. Wether you use `"`, `'` or nothing surrounding the expression does not matter in this case.