# How do I JS-Beautify recursively?

Tags: javascript, bash, shell

I have lots of HTML files in a directory and sub-directories. I can execute `js-beautify` command through the command line and want to apply it recursively to all those files.

I have tried

> find . -name "*.html" -type f | js-beautify -r`and`js-beautify -r | find . -name "*.html" -type f

but it doesn't work. However, JS-beautify does work if I give something like `js-beautify -r myfile.html` or `js-beautify -r *.html` (in case of all the files in a directory *but not in sub-directory*)

Can anyone tell me how should I be piping these two commands?

Comment: `find . -name "*.html" -type f -exec js-beautify -r {} \;`

Comment: @devnull ^^^ Looks good to me.  Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @PervySage How does it fail?  What errors (if any) do you get?

Comment: One possibility is that `js-beautify` doesn't like filenames with relative paths.  With these `find` invocations, filenames like `./foo.html` will get passed to `js-beautify`.  Perhaps `find $PWD -name ...` will work better.

Comment: @devnull - Your command works. As DigitalTrauma said, why not make it an answer? :)

Comment: When did `js-beautify` get the `-r` option? It's not listed in my help, and I have version 1.4.2.

Comment: @Merchako js-beautify is up to 1.6.12.   `-r` is "replace".  If anyone is interested, the issue tracking making js-beautify do recursive is https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/787 .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> However, JS-beautify does work ... in case of all the files in a directory but not in sub-directory

You've mentioned that JS-beautify works if all the input files are in the same directory.  Your command doesn't probably work because you pass all the results from `find` which might include input files from different directories.

As mentioned in the comment earlier, you could use `-exec` instead:

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;
```

Newer versions of GNU `find` might use this syntax:

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec js-beautify -r {} +
```

Comment: In case anyone is doing this on a Mac, and the -r command doesn't work, I've managed to get this working instead:
`find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec sh -c 'js-beautify {} >> {}' \;`

Comment: Or `find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec sh -c 'js-beautify {} > {}2;mv {}2 {}' \;` if it doesn't work fully. Maybe someone has a better/more efficient way of doing this in a line.

Comment: Probably this answer was working back in the time but currently it looks like js-beautify executing wrong beautifier on html files (probably js) if used within this command

Comment: @Tiago The second version worked for me, thanks! The first one only appends the "beautified" content to the files, resulting in duplicate content.

Answer (score 17):

I've run into a similar problem and found a simple cross-platform solution using [glob-run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-run):

```
npm i -g glob-run js-beautify
glob-run html-beautify -r **/*.html
```

It would be nice if js-beautify [supported globs itself](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/787), though.

Comment: Doesn't put quotes around or escape the dynamic path in `cmd.exe` or Git Bash.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I only did this as a one-off operation, so I don't know how well it really works. Feel free to improve this answer, point out a pitfall example or show how to do escaping properly. I see on the glob-run docs it suggests escaping like `\*` - does that work (cross-platform)?

Comment: I've already filed [an issue](https://github.com/fahad19/glob-run/issues/7). `js-beautify -r "blocks/block-search-results (class selection).html"` should work.

Answer (score 7):

find+xargs is the way to go. It is faster than find with -exec.

```
find . -name '*.html' | xargs js-beautify
```

If for some reason, you have spaces in your filenames, you'll want to do it like this...

```
find . -name '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 js-beautify
```

Finally, if for some strange reason, js-beautify won't work with multiple arguments, then you'll need to tell xargs to only pass in one argument at a time. This isn't much different than using the -exec option, but it's better IMO because it's just more consistent.

```
find . -name '*.html' | xargs -n 1 js-beautify
```

Note, you can combine the `-print0` and `xargs -0` options with `xargs -n 1`.

edit: As pointed out by T.J. Crowder, the shell will not glob wildcards in double-quotes. This was news to me, perhaps there is some ancient environment out there where that isn't true, and hopefully, you'll never be forced to work in it.

Comment: The shell will glob them if they're in double quotes? I've never run into that. (Which is to say: I've never missed out files in subdirectories matching the spec because the shell globbed only files in the current directory when I ran the command.)

Comment: If you downvote other answers on posts that you've answered, might as well consider leaving a note as to what could be improved in the answer.

Comment: @devnull I already stated why using the -exec option is not a good choice. In addition to the speed issue, which admittedly may not matter for everybody's problem size, the syntax for the -exec option is harder to explain. e.g. the \; Finally, knowing how xargs works is very useful in other situations. e.g. when you have a file of filenames you wish to execute a command on. That is how I feel on the matter. Despite all of this, you are correct. I should have left a comment instead. SO won't let me change the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was taught this by old AT&T Unix guys. It may have been true back in the day, however, I can't reproduce that on any shell that I have access to at the moment. I will amend the answer.

Comment: @Bill It's ok.  Your downvote is justified.  I can understand what you might have gone through.  You can find more of my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull?tab=answers).  Good luck!

Comment: @devnull Sorry, meant to say, SO won't let me change the downvote unless the answer has been edited.

Comment: Why does this answer not have the `-r` option?

Comment: Alas, `js-beautify` won't take multiple files as arguments as of 1.6.2.

Answer (score 6):

1) Add these dependencies to your project

```
npm install --save-dev glob js-beautify
```

2) Create `scripts/format.js`

```
const jsBeautify = require('js-beautify')['js_beautify'];
const fs = require('fs');
const glob = require('glob');

const options = {
  indent_size: 2,
  indent_char: ' ',
  indent_with_tabs: false,
  eol: '\n',
  end_with_newline: true,
  indent_level: 0,
  preserve_newlines: true,
  max_preserve_newlines: 10,
  space_in_paren: false,
  space_in_empty_paren: false,
  jslint_happy: false,
  space_after_anon_function: false,
  brace_style: 'collapse',
  break_chained_methods: false,
  keep_array_indentation: false,
  unescape_strings: false,
  wrap_line_length: 0,
  e4x: false,
  comma_first: false,
  operator_position: 'before-newline'
};

glob('**/!(node_modules)/**/*.js', { absolute: true }, (er, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(`js-beautify ${file}`);
    const data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    const nextData = jsBeautify(data, options);
    fs.writeFileSync(file, nextData, 'utf8');
  });
});
```

3) Add a `format` script to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "format": "node ./scripts/format.js"
}
```

4) In your project, run

```
npm run format
```

Comment: Works great! All Javascript content from the home project folder and its sub directories gets beautified.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like [file globs are supported](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/pull/1580) as of [v1.8.9](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/compare/v1.8.8...v1.8.9) (released December 2018). [For example](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/pull/1580#issuecomment-493651366):

```sh
js-beautify --html --replace '**/*.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining Bill's wisdom above and [these answers on regexp matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49876950/444255), **this is the actual solution for my project**:

find . -regextype egrep -regex './(src|test|app)/.*.(js|sass|html)' -print0 | xargs -0 ./node_modules/.bin/js-beautify -r

- only looks in the right folders (i.e. not node_modules)
- goes after js, sass, html
- can handle file names with spaces
- rewrites in place (`-r`)
- does not rely on the node shebang
- works with a locally installed js-beautify (`./node_modules/.bin`)

When used inside a package.json script, `./node_modules/.bin` is automatically in the path, `\.*` needs to be escaped to `\\.*`, thus:

```
"beautify2": "find . -regextype egrep -regex './(src|test|app)/.*\\.(js|sass|html)' -print0 | xargs -0 js-beautify -r"
```

→

```
beautified app/index.html
beautified app/sass/_atomic.sass
beautified app/sass/_mixin.sass
beautified app/sass/space test.sass
beautified test/Log.test.js
beautified test/deleteAction.test.js
beautified src/util/fileUtils.js
...
```

Comment: I had to add type to your command otherwise it errors once it hits the first folder:
    find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex './(src|test|app)/.*.(js|sass|html)' -print0 | xargs -0 ./node_modules/.bin/js-beautify -r

Answer (score 0):

Extending @devnull's answer, for macos users (just to make it easier to copy paste) here is what you need to add to your `.bash_profile` :

```
alias js-beautify-alljs='find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;'
alias js-beautify-alljsx='find . -type f -name "*.jsx" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;'
alias js-beautify-allts='find . -type f -name "*.ts" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;'
alias js-beautify-alltsx='find . -type f -name "*.tsx" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;'
alias js-beautify-allhtml='find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;'
alias js-beautify-allcss='find . -type f -name "*.css" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;'
alias js-beautify-allscss='find . -type f -name "*.scss" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;'
alias js-beautify-alljson='find . -type f -name "*.json" -exec js-beautify -r {} \;'
alias js-beautify-all='js-beautify-alljs && js-beautify-alljsx && js-beautify-allts && js-beautify-alltsx && js-beautify-allhtml && js-beautify-allcss && js-beautify-allscss && js-beautify-alljson;'
```

Then just run
`source ~/.bash_profile`
and then as per requirement

`js-beautify-alljs` or `js-beautify-alljsx` or `js-beautify-allts` or  `js-beautify-alltsx` or `js-beautify-allhtml` or `js-beautify-allcss` or `js-beautify-allscss` or `js-beautify-alljson`

or for all the 8 formats:

`js-beautify-all`