# Recursively find files with a specific extension

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to find files with specific extensions. 
For example, I want to find all .pdf and .jpg files that's named Robert

I know I can do this command

```
$ find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp'
```

but I need to specify the name of the file itself besides the extensions. 
I just want to see if there's a possible way to avoid writing the file name again and over again
Thank you !

Comment: Anyone copying this command, or any below it, should use `iname` instead - which is **case insensitive**.

Comment: Good point, Addison (hence the +1). However, it seems that the OP wants files named 'Robert' with a capital 'R'. As I interpret the post, this means that files containing 'robert' should NOT be outputted. '**R**obert` is what's written. However, there are situations when someone would want either 'Robert' or 'robert' to be found. Maybe the OP is in this situation. Whether to use `iname` or `name` depends on what you want to find. I've been in situations where the case was essential.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

My preference:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' -print | grep Robert
```

Comment: Works nicely, but slight disadvantage is that it precludes you from doing a `find -exec ...`

Comment: what if I want find all xxx-deployment.yml files in all folders in a specific path?

Comment: This doesn't work so well if you have `jpg` or `png` as part of a longer path.

Answer (score 23):

Using `find`'s `-regex` argument:

```
find . -regex '.*/Robert\.\(h\|cpp\)$'
```

Or just using `-name`:

```
find . -name 'Robert.*' -a \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
find -name "*Robert*" \( -name "*.pdf" -o -name "*.jpg" \)
```

The `-o` repreents an `OR` condition and you can add as many as you wish within the braces. So this says to find all files containing the word "Robert" anywhere in their names and whose names end in either "pdf" or "jpg".

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using `-regex` option on `find`, since the question is labeled [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can use the brace expansion mechanism:

```
eval find . -false "-o -name Robert".{jpg,pdf}
```

Comment: find report "paths must precede expression", what's the problem? I usually   add quote to resolve it, but don't work for this expression. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you either forgot `eval` or the `.` in the command above, or your `find` is an alias for something more complicated, or you are not using the stock GNU `find` on your version of Linux.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I used a script like this: FILEEXTEIONS=cs,[ch]  eval find . -false "-o -name *".{$FILEEXTEIONS}, and it report that error.

Comment: As far as I know, variable expansion will not occur inside the brace expansion braces.

Comment: oh, I continue tried eval find . -false "-o -name *".{cs,config}, it report the same error.

Comment: If you are using glob expansion characters, escape them with `\ ` when passing to `eval`.

Comment: finally eval find . -false "-o -name \*".{cs,config} is OK now, thanks very much!

Comment: I wanted to use this technique in an Android shell but its `find` does not support `-false`.  I worked around this by giving two mutually-exclusive conditions so they are collectively false: `-inum 1 -inum 2`.

Answer (score 2):

This q/a shows how to use find with regular expression: [How to use regex with find command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command)

Pattern could be something like

```
'^Robert\\.\\(h|cgg\\)$'
```

Answer (score 1):

As a script you can use:

```
find "${2:-.}" -iregex ".*${1:-Robert}\.\(h\|cpp\)$" -print
```

- save it as `findcc`
- chmod 755 findcc

and use it as

```
findcc [name] [[search_direcory]]
```

e.g.

```
findcc                 # default name 'Robert' and directory .
findcc Joe             # default directory '.'
findcc Joe /somewhere  # no defaults
```

note you cant use

```
findcc /some/where    #eg without the name...
```

also as alternative, you can use

```
find "$1" -print | grep "$@"
```

and

```
findcc directory grep_options
```

like

```
findcc . -P '/Robert\.(h|cpp)$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash globbing (if `find` is not a must)

```
ls Robert.{pdf,jpg}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recurisvely with ls: (-al for include hidden folders)

```
ftype="jpg"
ls -1R *.${ftype}  2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding the files in system using the files database:

```
locate -e --regex "\.(h|cpp)$"
```

Make sure `locate` package is installed i.e. [mlocate](https://github.com/msekletar/mlocate)