# Find all files ending in extension in bash

Tags: bash

Write a bash script accepting two arguments: directory and extension.
The script must print to stdout the path of all files in directory (and,
recursively, its sub-directories) with a name ending with extension.

So far I have:

```
find {directory} -type f -name ' *.extension *
```

when I give it 2 args it doesn't seem to find anything.

Comment: You have an unmatched quote. What is the `*` at the end for?

Answer (score 6):

This script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -type f -name "*.$2"
```

Examples to run the script:

```
/bin/bash script.sh /srv/directory css
/bin/bash script.sh '/srv/directory with space' css
```

Answer (score 5):

In this answer, I'm just giving some explanation for Viktor's code.

This explanation might help those of you who are learning `bash`. Viktor updated his answer after I posted the "space issue" part and before I finished writing and saving this explanation. That's what I hoped for.

It is very concise, and there are great explanations. The original code was:

```
#!/bin/bash
#@filename: script.sh

find $1 -type f -name "*.$2"
```

It sounds like the question came from some kind of assignment, and I imagine that this original code *might* fulfill the assignment's expectations. It will probably also work with *most* programs you will write, which is especially important if the question did not come from an assignment.

I often develop on Windows or Cygwin, so I run into paths and filenames that have spaces. If I use @Viktor's code on Cygwin (note that the same behavior happens when I use Viktor's code on linux)

```
$ pwd
/home/bballdave025

#Write the program
$ vim script.sh

#view the program
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

find $1 -type f -name "*.$2"


#Create a path with spaces in one of the directory names
#Name it after Viktor, for the great answer
bballdave025@MYMACHINE ~
$ mkdir -p viktor/dir\ with\ spaces/directory

#put some css files in that directory
$ touch viktor/dir\ with\ spaces/directory/a.css

$ touch viktor/dir\ with\ spaces/directory/b.css

$ touch viktor/dir\ with\ spaces/directory/c.css

# run Viktor's code, using the well-written instructions
$ /bin/bash ./script.sh 'victor/dir with spaces/directory' css
find: ‘viktor/dir’: No such file or directory
find: ‘spaces/directory’: No such file or directory
```

Note that I used `./script.sh` rather than plain `script.sh`, because I had not set `script.sh` to be executable. I can run it as Viktor shows if I first run

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
```

The problem comes from the way a `bash` shell and the `find` command handle spaces. With the first argument given simply as `$1`, the spaces aren't treated a special way. That's probably not the best way to describe things. Perhaps a better way of explaining this concept is to show that `bash` will assign the following - i.e. bash will use an unintended assignment pattern - when the script is written as above.

```
$0='script.sh'
$1='viktor/dir'
$2='with'
$3='spaces/directory'
$4='css'
```

[Note: what we want is to have things interpreted as]

```
$0='script.sh'
$1='viktor/dir with spaces/directory'
$2='css'
```

[and we will get to how to accomplish this, later.]

This unintended assignment pattern will happen even if we tell `bash` that our directory has spaces

```
$ /bin/bash script.sh viktor/dir\ with\ spaces/directory css
find: ‘viktor/dir’: No such file or directory
find: ‘spaces/directory’: No such file or directory
```

This can be seen by adding to the script the lines, `echo "\$0 is $0"` , `echo "\$1 is $1"` , `echo "\$2 is $2"` , and further with other lines having `$(insert_number_here_but_no_parentheses)`, if you'd like.

So, how do we fix this problem? Let's look at the man page for `find`

```
$ man find

# (press 'q' to get out of the display of the man page)
```

Okay, that was kind of scary.

Let's cut the original synopsis line down to

```
find  [starting-point...] [expression]
```

What the DESCRIPTON means in its 'starting-point' explanation is that `[starting-point...]` is a directory (or directories) from which you'll start your search. For now, just take it at face value that 'expression' is something that restricts the search -- in your case, you look for only files and then further filter the results by specifying that they have a certain file-extension.

Let's get back to the `find $1 -type f -name "*.$2"` command. The main point to know here is that the command as shown here will be expanded to

```
find viktor/dir with spaces/directory -type f -name "*.css"
```

The "space problem" is that it will be interpreted by `find` and by the shell as follows

```
find victor/dir with spaces/directory -type f -name "*.css"
 |     \         |      \             `--------------------'
 |      \        |       \              /
 |       |       |        \       Another '[expression]' (2)
 |       |       |         -- Another '[starting-point]'
 |       |        -- '[expression]' (1)
 |        -- '[starting-point]' (supposedly a directory)
  -- Command name
```

Note that our `'[expression]' (1)` and `'[expression]' (2)` don't factor into what happens because the two `'[starting-place]'` paths fail.

What's now shown in Viktor's code

```
#!/bin/bash
#@filename viktor_script.sh

find "$1" -type f -name "*.$2"
```

Leads to

```
find "viktor/dir with spaces/directory" -type f -name "*.css"
`--' `--------------------------------' `-------------------'
 |               |                             /
 |               |             valid '[expression]' to define
 |               |             a "filter" for files outputted
 |               |
 |                -- '[starting-point]' (a real directory)
 |                    bash knows to include the spaces because
  -- command name                    of the quotation marks
```

Let's run it, first making sure it's executable

```
$ chmod +x viktor_script.sh

$ /bin/bash ./viktor_script.sh css

$ /bin/bash viktor_script.sh 'viktor/dir with spaces/directory' css
viktor/dir with spaces/directory/a.css
viktor/dir with spaces/directory/b.css
viktor/dir with spaces/directory/c.css
```

Comment: You are right. I updated my script to wrap the directory in double quotes so it takes space input correctly.

Comment: This is a great answer, and it should be said that answers that build on other answers are very welcome on Stack Overflow; the CC license conditions explicitly allow it. There is no need to put any disclaimers about this in the post, nor to direct people how to vote.

Comment: Thanks @halfer for helping me to understand some of the meta stuff, and thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t look like you are using arguments here.

You should replace extension and directory with $1 and $2 to use arguments 1 and 2.

Also, it looks like you forgot to close that quote... and the braces around the directory look wrong... I think you need quotes around the braces.

(Can’t test the result unfortunately at the minute, sorry).

Comment: Okay I have changed it to    find "$1" -type f -name "*$2" but it doesnt print the files

Comment: Try referring here, it’s similar but had a slightly more complex requirement.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694217/857994.  Maybe you need a -print?

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te `-print` is the default.

Comment: @jsmith147 That should work, although I'd write `"*.$2"`, so it requires a `.` before the extension.

Comment: @jsmith147 Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so you can see the variable expansions.