# Conversion of Source Code to PDF from GitHub

Tags: bash, shell, pdf, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to take all files from a specific repository I have on GitHub and turn them into PDF's. I have read and seen an example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/601198/how-can-i-automatically-convert-all-source-code-files-in-a-folder-recursively)

However, I am still a bit confused on how to go about doing this. I have to take all my files and turn them into a single PDF file to upload it to a site for college.

I am not extremely familiar with UNIX commands and I was trying to do the following:

```
for i in *.lua; do echo "$i"; echo "---"; cat "$i"; echo ; done > result.pdf
```

Then I was going to take all the pdfs and merge them together, but I was hoping there was a better way to go about doing this. I'm specifically dealing with only `.lua` and `.md` file-extensions.

I personally believe this can be done with the use of some UNIX commands, but as mentioned, I am not familiar with them.

To summarize, my main objective is to take a series of files located on a repository on Github and merge them into one PDF file. Even obtaining multiple PDF files is *ok* is that is the best that can be done. Even a `.word` file format is good enough.

***Operating System***: OSX or Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: You can't just redirect some output to a PDF file and expect it to be a valid PDF.  PDF has a specific format.

Comment: @ctc Thanks for the response! What would be your suggestion on going about doing this? I'm fine even with a `.word` format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest looking into a syntax highlighter.  [Pygments](http://pygments.org) has the ability to generate HTML, RTF, etc.  If you chose to output HTML files, you could then use a tool like [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to convert the syntax-highlighted HTML files to PDF files.

Alternatively, Pygments can do LaTeX.  If you're familiar with LaTeX, then you can have Pygments generate LaTeX output, and use `pdflatex` to generate your PDF files.

You said you're on OS X.  To install Pygments, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo easy_install Pygments
```

This will install a program `pygmentize` that you can use to transform code.

Next, install [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html#stable).

Now, you can take a file, syntax highlight it, and convert it to PDF:

```
pygmentize -l ruby -f html -O full,style=vim test.rb > test.html
wkhtmltopdf test.html test.pdf
```

Here, I show the conversion of a Ruby script.  Of course, you'd want to use `-l lua` if you're converting Lua scripts.

You can then incorporate these commands into a shell script that traverses over a directory recursively, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change this to the repository directory
REPOSITORY=/path/to/the/repo

# Iterate over the repository
while read source_file
do
  filename=$(basename $source_file)
  dir=$(dirname $source_file)

  # For each .lua file found, generate an HTML file in /tmp
  pygmentize -l lua -f html -O full,style=vim $source_file > /tmp/${filename}.html

  # Convert the HTML file to a PDF file in the same directory 
  # as the .lua file
  wkhtmltopdf /tmp/${filename}.html ${dir}/${filename}.pdf

done < <(find $REPOSITORY -type f -iname '*.lua')
```

Put this in a file named `convert.sh`.  Then, to run it, type:

```
chmod +x convert.sh
./convert.sh
```

Comment: You haven't specified what operating system you're using.  This would be helpful to know in order to suggest the appropriate commands to use to install this software.

Comment: I have both OSX and Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: I have edited the answer to show you how you would approach the problem on OS X.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing (sorry, very unfamiliar with UNIX paths) If my repo is under my 'Downloads' in a folder called 'Lua-Research', what would my REPOSITORY path be?

Comment: Most likely `~/Downloads/Lua-Research`.  To be sure, you can find out using Finder: http://lifehacker.com/5102717/show-a-folders-full-path-in-finders-title-bar

Comment: You can also, of course, try typing `cd ~/Downloads/Lua-Research`.  If that works and contains the files you expect (type `ls`), then you know you got the directory right.

Comment: i tried the bash code above, but it didnt iterate all files. but the line `<(find $REPOSITORY -type f -iname '*.lua')` will always produce `/dev/fd/63`. what is this `<(...)` command?

Comment: it was [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst). what happened was there is mistake in my find command. i wrote '-iname '*.(ts|tsx)''. weirdly it cannot parse regex

Comment: Correct -- `find` doesn't support regular expressions with the `-iname` parameter.  There are [other parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command), however, that allow you to specify a regular expression.