# Ignore list of files in Find command Linux/ Unix

Tags: linux, unix, find

I would like to ignore list of files from the `find` command :

```
find .  \( -name file1-o -name file2 \)
```

In the above format, I have to give files individually. Can I put them into an array instead??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no, you can't put the files to ignore into an array and expect to have `find` know about them.  An array is an artifact of your shell (bash I assume), and the `find` tool is a separate binary, outside your shell.

That said, you can use an array to generate options for find.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a=(file1 file2 file3)

declare -a fopt=()
for f in "${a[@]}"; do
  if [ "${#fopt[@]}" -eq 0 ]; then
    fopt+=("-name '$f'")
  else
    fopt+=("-o -name '$f'")
  fi
done

echo "find . -not ( ${fopt[@]} )"
```

There's no doubt a more elegant way to handle the exclusion of `-o` from the first file found that {Dennis,chepner,Etan,Jonathan,Glenn} will point out, but I haven't had coffee yet this morning.

Comment: thanks for the quick response adding this to my existing script is easier

Answer (score 0):

`find` supports regular expressions. See [How to use regex with find command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command).
If your file names have some kind of pattern this could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Posix extended regex are a good way to go

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*(scriptA|scriptB)[0-9]\.pl'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `File::Find` in `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my @skip_names = qw( skip_this_file.txt
                     not_this_either
                   ); 
my %skip = map { $_ => 1 } @skip_names; 


sub finder {
    next if $skip{$_}; 
    ## do everything else. 
}

find ( \&finder, "/path/to/find_in" );
```

You can read your filenames out of a file, or inline the array. Or use regular expression tests as well.