# Find files after a folder using regex on the Linux command line

Tags: regex, linux, shell, command-line

I have some folders like:

```
SRGRG-3DDD-E7DHC-VUDND4-8
EHFAWFH-AWF8WF-WF74H4-G9799
HDSRJ86-FJJ-SU8USH-DYYDCJ0
```

Inside them some files like:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I am on a Linux environment. How can I use a `find` on the command line with a regex to find the file paths. So for `file1` I get this path `SRGRG-3DDD-E7DHC-VUDND4-8`
And so on

(I know the file names. Just need their paths)

IT ISN'T A DUPLICATE. I NEED SOMETHING DIFFERENT, SPECIFIC TO WHAT I WANT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use regex with find command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command)

Comment: In other words, you need someone to write it for you. This is not a good way to learn and will ensure that you forever remain 'NEW TO THIS'. Why not try yourself and then post a specific question for when you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

No regex needed, just use the `name` option:

```
find -name file1 -o -name file2 -o -name file3
```

Or, use a pattern:

```
find -name 'file[123]'
```

Regexes match the whole path, so you need to prefix it with `.*`:

```
find -regex '.*/file[123]'
```

Comment: Will this work if the file is inside a subdirectory?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What are the real paths and filenames?

Comment: The paths are UUID's of apps. Inside the paths are some other paths (Library/Preferences) and inside Preferences is located a file that has the app name (I am talking about iOS apps, on a jailbroken phone)