# Exclude files and directories from find . function that match some regular expression

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, dash-shell

I am using Bash to go through some directories and files. I am using find function as shown in the example and I need to exclude all directories (and all it includes) and files which name match some regular expression (which can be anything).

```
while read file
do 
    do_stuff "${file}" 
done <<< "$(find ${SOME_DIR}")
```

I already tried using -not -name args but that only excluded that one specific directory, and processed all in that directory.

Btw. I found some similar questions in here, but all are quite specific. This regular expression can be really anything.

example: REGEX='^bbb$'

dir structure:
./test

├── bbb

│   └── some file

├── -e

├── dir2

│   └── bbb

├── a

├── b

└── c

So here I would like find to exclude bbb directory and all thats in it and bbb file.

Another regex example:
'^.*b.*$' -- all files and directories that has b in their name

Comment: please add examples, show sample directory structure, whether they are nested or not, add sample filenames and explain which files are needed and which are not

Comment: @Sundeep added example

Comment: I didn't mean you need to draw structure itself... anyway, so in shown example, you want to exclude any file/dir named `bbb`.. that is clear... what about `some file` under `bbb` directory, that should also be excluded?

Comment: Yes, all that the directory contains, so also `some file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options.  Closest to what you asked, if you are using GNU `find` then you can use a negated `-regex` test to filter out the files you don't want to see.  Since this matches against the whole path to each file (relative to one of the starting directories) you can write a regex that matches both paths ending with your file name and those having that name as an intermediate directory.  For example,

```
find . -not -regex '\(.*/\)?bbb\(/.*\)?'
```

(Note that anchoring the pattern is unnecessary, as the test succeeds only if the pattern matches the whole path under consideration anyway.)

But better might be to use a negated filename test combined with the `-prune` action, something like this:

```
find . -not -name 'bbb' -o \( -prune -false \)
```

The `-name` test compares the base file name of each file considered with the specified *shell pattern* (glob), and the result is negated by the `-not` operator.  The right-hand expression of the `-o` (logical or) operator is evaluated only if the left-hand expression evaluates to false, and in that case it performs the `-prune` action before ultimately evaluating to false itself. Thus, files with the given name are suppressed (by `-false`) and their descendants, if any, are not scanned at all (because of `-prune`).  All of this is portable to any POSIX-conformant `find`.

Comment: nice one, to clarify some points for OP, can you mention that -name specified is [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and not regex? and possibly an example with `-regex` option which has syntax differences and requirement to match path, etc

Comment: so if I replace `-name` with `-regex`, it should work?

Comment: For the first part of the answer: so I should somehow work with the regex to make it match the whole path? And if so, is there an easy way?

Comment: @Zeusko see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command for examples with -regex

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks for your suggestions.  I have implemented them.

Comment: @Zeusko, you can use `-regex` to solve the problem (supposing you can rely on having GNU's version of `find`), but the semantics are not exactly analogous to those of `-name`.  I have updated the answer with an example.  Nevertheless, unless you need to support regexes that cannot easily be replaced by shell globs, I recommend instead the approach based on `-name` that I outlined.  It's more portable and easier to read.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for advice `-regex` will probably work for me.