# Regex with find command in bash

Tags: regex, bash, find

I have been trying to use regex with find command in bash. Following are my codes:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex 'AB[0-9]{1}_all_chr\.gz'
```

However, above code did not match to desired file with id such as "AB1_all_chr.gz" and "AB2_all_chr.gz". can someone help me out with this piece of code?

Comment: Needs `.*` at the start, you need the entire path to be a match. Also `[0-9]{1}` is redundant `[0-9]` already does a single char.

Comment: See [How to use regex with find command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command)

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

So, to provide an actual answer:

`find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*AB[0-9]_all_chr\.gz$'`

Match any text at the beginning followed by `AB` and then any one digit and then ending with `_all_chr.gz`