# Grep multiple files using regex for specifying filenames to search for

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Let's say I have `n` files with names like `link123.txt`, `link345.txt`, `link645.txt`, etc.

I'd like to grep a subset of these `n` files for a keyword. For example:

```bash
grep 'searchtext' link123.txt link 345.txt ...
```

I'd like to do something like

```bash
grep 'searchtext' link[123\|345].txt
```

How can I mention the filenames as regex in this case?

Comment: In simple command lines, you have only filename globbing, which is a crippled kind of regex that can't handle the example you've given.  You can probably write a bash script that accepts a program name (like `grep`) and a regex and does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the bash option [`extglob`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889744/what-is-the-purpose-of-shopt-s-extglob), which allows extended use of globbing, including `|` separated pattern lists.

```
@(123|456)
```

Matches one of `123` or `456` once.

```
shopt -s extglob
grep 'searchtext' link@(123|345).txt
shopt -u extglob
```

Comment: this solution does not seem to work on my bash 4.3.48. error is unexpected token `(`

Comment: are you setting extglob?

Comment: I think so. I run "shopt -s extglob" first.

Comment: oh yeah, my bad, missed an important character

Answer (score 5):

you can use `find` and `grep` together like this

```
find . -regex '.*/link\(123\|345\).txt' -exec grep 'searchtext' {} \;
```

Thanks for ghoti's comment.

Comment: As you've proposed it, this answer suffers from the same ails as [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you must use `xargs`, consider find's `-print0` option along with `xargs -0`. Or better yet, use `find .. -exec`, either the traditional way or with `\+` as the command terminator so that only a single instance of `grep` needs to be run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably asking for `find` functionality to search for filenames with regex.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command), you can easely use `find . -regex '.*/link\([0-9]\{3\}\).txt'` to show all these three files. Now you have only to play with regex.

PS: Don't forget to specify `.*/` in the beginning of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you don't need regex to determine the files to grep, since you enumerate them all (well, actually you enumerate the *minimal unique part* without repeating common prefix/suffix).

If regex functionality is not needed and the only aim is to avoid repeating common prefix/suffix, then simple iterating would be an option:

`for i in 123 345 645; do grep searchpattern link$i.txt; done`