# Find all files containing the filename of specific date range on Terminal/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, file-find

I have a surveillance camera which is capturing image base on my given condition. The images are saved on my Linux. Image naming convention are given below-

```
CAPTURE04.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.jpg
```

The directory contains the following files -

```
CAPTURE04.20171020080501.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171021101309.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171021101913.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171021102517.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171021103422.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171022103909.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171022104512.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171022105604.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171022110101.jpg
CAPTURE04.20171022112513.jpg ... and so on.
```

However, Actually, now I'm trying to find a way to get all files between a specific date time (filename) range by using the terminal command.
**Note: Need to follow the filename (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS), not the file created/modified time.**

Such as I need to get all files whose file name is between 2017-10-20 08:30:00 and 2017-10-22 09:30:00

I'm trying and searching google around and got the following command -

```
find -type f -newermt "2017-10-20 08:30:00" \! -newermt "2017-10-22 09:30:00" -name '*.jpg'
```

It returns the files which are created/modified on that given date range. But I need to find files base on the given filenames range. So I think it does not work on my condition.

Also trying with the following command-

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size +1c -type f \( -name 'CAPTURE04.20171020083000*.jpg' -o -name 'CAPTURE04.2017102209300*.jpg' \) | sort -n
```

This is not working.. :(

Please help me to write the actual command. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I think this can help you: [Find with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command)

Comment: Ok. I'm checking. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete **find** + **bash** solution:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*CAPTURE04\.[0-9]{14}\.jpg" -exec bash -c \
'fn=${0##*/}; d=${fn:10:-4}; 
 [[ $d -ge 20171020083000 && $d -le 20171022093000 ]] && echo "$0"' {} \;
```

---

- `fn=${0##*/}` - obtaining file *basename*
- `d=${fn:10:-4}` - extracting *datetime* section from the file's *basename*
- `[[ $d -ge 20171020083000 && $d -le 20171022093000 ]] && echo "$0"` - print the filepath only if its *datetime* "section" is in specified range

Comment: I'm working with your given command. I have lots of file in the folder. Is this is the efficient way to do that type of searching? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Sharif, this solution is unified to search the crucial files `CAPTURE04.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.jpg` that can be placed in any location (i.e. subfolders/ same-level directories). For global search you can just specify the "root" starting point `find / -type f ....`. As for the perfprmance: you are free to compare and measure through all the posted answers on your own

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest If my filename in this format **CAM04.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.jpg**. What will be the code? Would you plz have look the follwing code...
`find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*CAM04\.[0-9]{14}\.jpg" -exec bash -c \ 'fn=${0##*/}; d=${fn:6:-4}; [[ $d -ge 20171020083000 && $d -le 20171022093000 ]] && echo "$0"' {} \;` Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Sharif, yes, that looks operable

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Need help... I got an error when trying by the following filename format - **CAM.04.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.mp4.vRandomString.th.jpg** Such as _CAM.04.20171021170115.mp4.v2474.th.jpg_ , _CAM.04.20171021170022.mp4.v2473.th.jpg_ etc. 
Trying with the following code  `find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*CAM\.04\.[0-9]{14}\.mp4\.[a-z0-9]*\.th\.jpg" -exec bash -c \ 'fn=${0##*/}; d=${fn:7:-4}; [[ $d -ge 20171020083000 && $d -le 20171022235959 ]] && echo "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: _Error_
**./CAM.04.20170301235959.mp4.v2475.th.jpg: [[: 20170301235959.mp4.v2475.th: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".mp4.v2475.th")**

Eagerly waiting for your response.

Comment: @Sharif, that's obvious that you got errors, cause you have changed your filename convention. That's another case

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Some files are in that format. Would you plz tell me what I need to add/modify in the code to work that type of filename format.

Comment: @Sharif, the crucial slice for new filenames should be `d=${fn:7:14};` Here you go

Answer (score 1):

One way(bash), not an elegant one:

```
ls  CAPTURE04.2017102008{30..59}*.jpg CAPTURE04.2017102009{00..30}*.jpg 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

as maxdepth option is used means all files are in current directory so can be done in a loop with globs

```
for file in CAPTURE04.201710{20..22}*.jpg; do
    if [[ $file > CAPTURE04.20171020083000 && $file < CAPTURE04.2017102209300 ]]; then
        ... do something with "$file"
    fi
done
```