# Get list of files with `ls` using template `file{1..n}` in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ls

I can create some files in my dir using template:

```
touch file{1..3}
```

For get list of files I use command:

```
ls file{1..3}
```

Output:

> file1  file2  file3

But when I have tried to use same command with variables in bash script:

```
#/bin/bash
a=1
b=3
ls file{$a..$b}
```

I got error:

> ls: cannot access 'file{1..3}': No such file or directory

How I understand problem is that bash interprets `file{1..3}` as name of file, but not as template.
I have tried to fix it but didn't help. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) happens before [Variable Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (see [order of expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)).

So bash sees:

```
file{$a..$b}
```

and first tries to do brace expansion. As `$a` and `$b` (interpreted as dollar with a character, this is *before* variable expansion) are not a valid brace expansion token, because they need to be a single character or a number, so nothing happens in brace expansion. After it (and some other expansions) variable expansion happens and `$a` and `$b` get expanded to `1` and `3`, so the resulting argument is `"file{1..3}"`.

For you simple use case, with no spaces and/or special characters in fielnames, I would just:

```
ls $(seq -f file%.0f "$a" "$b")
```

or

```
seq -f file%.0f "$a" "$b" | xargs ls
```

or

```
seq "$a" "$b" | xargs -I{} ls file{}
```

or

```
seq "$a" "$b" | sed 's/^/file/' | xargs ls
```

or

```
seq "$a" "$b" | xargs printf "file%s\n" | xargs ls
```

Answer (score 1):

For the line

`ls file{$a..$b}`

you could use instead:

`eval ls file{$a..$b}`

Check [[Bash Reference]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: `eval` is evil.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general type solution, ditching the `ls` could be potentially to use `find`. For example in combination with `regex`, although this might be tricky (see [How to use regex with find command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command)):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1
b=3
find . -regex "./file[$a-$b]"
```

Comment: It is not so good way. Let's say that we have 100 files. In this case I should set `b=100`. Script will show only file `./file1`

Comment: for that case: `find . -regex "./file[0-9]+"`. I mean, you can modify the regex as it fits your real problem. :)  https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html

Comment: Yes, this could be different cases. Therefore  I need correctly find files with required  ranges of numbers in names for checking. It can 20, 30 or 100 files, why I use variables in script.