# How to delete common files under subfolders in mac using terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

i have directory like

dir A

--B file a

--c file a

--D file a

A is parent dir and B, C and D are child of A and all child folder contain a file a which i want to delete in one go using terminal. I tried below cmd but did not work

```
find. -regex '\b[FreeCoursesOnline.Me].url\b' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: Best to debug this with `find . .... | xargs -0 echo rm`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your method that's wrong - it's just your regex.

[How to use regex with find command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844785/how-to-use-regex-with-find-command) talks about using the regex with the find command, and what regex flavor it might support.  In any case, `[` and `]` have special meaning.  Outside of `[]`, `.` also has special meaning.  As far as I could determine with a quick glance, none of the `find` implementations I saw provided a regex engine that supported the `\b` word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly but below cmd can work

```
find . -name '*.txt' -delete
```

we can find out all the all the file with specific extension and can delete in one go