# Match optional pattern with find command

Tags: regex, find

I want to match all files with a typical fortran file extension with find. Typical extensions are .f .F .for .FOR .f90 .F90 .f95 .F95 .f03 .F03 .f08 .F08 .f15 .F15 .f18 .F18

what I tried so far is `find * -name "*\.[Ff][0-9Oo][0-9Rr]"` this works for all the mentioned extensions despite .f and .F. For that I have to make [0-9Oo] and [0-9Rr] optional which is usually done with "?". However, this `find * -name "*\.[Ff][0-9Oo]?[0-9Rr]?"` does not work with my version of find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a GNU `find`, you can use

```bash
find * -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.[Ff][0-9Oo]?[0-9Rr]?'
```

The pattern matches a string that fully matches:

- `.*\.` - any text up to the rightmost `.` including it
- `[Ff]` - `F` or `f`
- `[0-9Oo]?` - an optional digit, `O` or `o`
- `[0-9Rr]?` - an optional digit, `R` or `r`.

You can also use a non-regex approach using mere glob patterns:

```bash
find * ( -name "*.[Ff][0-9oO][0-9rR]" -o -name "*.[Ff]" )
```

Note that here, the `*` glob pattern matches any text. In the previous solution, it was a quantifier, an operator that makes the preceding pattern match zero or more times. Also, in glob patterns, `.` matches a literal dot, no need to escape it.

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to achieve the same with the 'findutils-default' regex type?

Comment: @M0M0 Try `find * -regex '.*\.[Ff][0-9Oo]\{0,1\}[0-9Rr]\{0,1\}'`

Comment: This one does not work for me.

Comment: @M0M0 Then forget about using the default flavor. It is broken.

Comment: ok, can I be sure that -regextype posix-extended will work for all versions of find?

Comment: @M0M0 I only use Linux. See [How to use regex with find command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6844785/3832970) where you can see how this can be "converted" to a MacOS (FreeBSD) `find`.

Comment: Ok, since I need it to work on MacOS as well, I will probably stay with my less elegant solution: find * \\( -name "*\.[Ff][0-9oO][0-9rR]" -o -name "*\.[Ff]" \\)

Comment: if you add, that your solution works only for GNU find, I will accept your answer anyway. Thanks again!